# Applying Angular filter results in broken layout

Tags: css, angularjs

I defined an Angular filter that prepends a `+` or `-` character to an integer value depending on its value. The value is centered using a CSS class.

It seems however that the prepended character is not taken into account when being centered by the browser...

What would be a valid workaround?

---

ANGULAR

```
angular.module('app', [])
.filter('customFormatter', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return (input > 0 ? '+ ' : '- ') + input;
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-block">
    {{ value | customFormatter }}
</button>
```

CSS

```
.btn {
   /* Default Bootstrap class */
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code.

Comment: It would help to know exactly what the markup and css looks like.

Comment: Please review the edit

Comment: Propaganistas can you change this [codepen](http://codepen.io/bobleujr/pen/RWbNBO) to show your problem? I am trying to get to it

Comment: Nevermind, it seems this was caused by insufficient space due to button padding. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVbdYW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it seems this was caused by insufficient space due to button padding. See codepen.io/anon/pen/bVbdYW